# file_get_contents now working as expected - external domain works same domain doesn't

Tags: php, xml-parsing, file-get-contents

This is a wordpress blog rss feed

From domain1, when using this script it will work for domain2 but not domain1.

From domain2, when using this script it works for both domain2 and domain1

my assumption is that it must be a permissions error, but I don't know what is not set properly (domain2 can fetch the blog fine for both domains, and domain1 will fetch the blog for domain2, but not domain1)

Same results when trying to use cURL, domain1 can fetch domain2, but not domain1 while domain2 can fetch feed from both domain1 and domain2

**file_get_contents**

```
    $feedUrl = 'http://domain1.com/blog/feed/'; 
    $feedUrl = 'http://domain2.com/blog/feed/';

    $rawFeed = file_get_contents($feedUrl);

    $xml = new SimpleXmlElement($rawFeed);
    $i = 0;

    foreach($xml->channel->item as $post)
    {
        $post->link = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $post->link);
        $date = new DateTime($post->pubDate);

        if($i == 5) break;      // number of feed items
        $title = '<a href="' . $post->link . '" title="' . $post->title . '" class="feed-link">' . $post->title . '</a>';
?>
        <p><?php echo $title; ?></p>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }

?>
```

**cURL**

```
<?php 
    $feedUrl = 'http://domain1.com/blog/feed/'; 
    $feedUrl = 'http://domain2.com/blog/feed/';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $feedUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-type: text/xml'
    ));
    $rawFeed = curl_exec($ch);
    $error   = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($rawFeed);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($obj);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**URL styles I have tried and results**

```
/www/domain1/blog/feed/ (file or folder does not exist, which is accurate)
http://domain1.com/blog/feed/ (timeout)
http://555.555.555.555/blog/feed (ip address) (timeout)
```

Comment: Just wondering, but why would you need to call a page like that from the same domain? Isn't the page on the same server? Can't you just include it or at least just read the source and find how it is generated and duplicate that?

Comment: Include your cURL request too...

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: @AbraCadaver, the error is a timeout error, but when calling it from `domain2` there is no timeout, its quite fast... also calling `domain2`'s blog from `domain1` is fast as well

@JonathanKuhn, if you could provide a sample code to fetch a wordpress blog locally I would love to see it, all code I have seen is using either `cURL` or the method I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem was server related...

from server admin `Added www.domain1.com to the /etc/hosts file so that it looked to itself for the site.`

Thank you everyone for your help, hopefully this will help anyone else who has a similar issue in the future

Answer (score 0):

I would start from those points:

**1. DNS issue?** 
Maybe issue with DNS table on your server2 (which can not resolve domain2).
from script try to execute function
 `string gethostbyname ( string $hostname )`

OR to check quickly, you also can try to use IP instead of domainname. If it would work the problem was with DNS table. Try to flush DNS caches.

**2. Filtration on server?**
If you are using common hosting, try to write in support too. maybe they can assist. Maybe they are using filtration.

If domain2 is yours OR you have access to its logs. Check access log. If you really get requests from your server2 to domain2.

**3. Are you in blacklist of server2?**
Also possible that your server2 IP in black list of domain2 service.

Comment: using IP address in place of domain name gives same timeout error... I can access blog XML feed directly by posting `$feedUrl` into the browser... for 2 & 3 I have sent questions to the server administrator

Comment: Try to fetch content from "http://domain2.com/". At least we will understand if we have problem with whole domain OR only with feed. + try to use php exec time_limit=0

Also I would dump `$rawFeed` (but I'm sure you already did it) to be sure that issue not in parsing logic (maybe you've got non-Xml response,etc..). In cUrl request you can also set `CURLOPT_HEADER` = true. To see response headers. Also you can use `curl_getinfo()`. If connection fails with code 28, try to use `CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL` = true (sometimes actual for *nix systems with connection timeout interval < 1000).

Comment: I tried fetching information from the index page of domain1 (domain I am having trouble with) and got no data (timeout), while when trying to fetch data fro domain2 (my test case) I had no trouble getting data... as far as `curl_getinfo()` I got a `header_size` result of 0... when running the script found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php#41332 I got a `Connection timed out after 30006 milliseconds` error, Also, no error code reported(0)

Comment: Okay, the problem was server related... from server admin `Added www.domain1.com to the /etc/hosts file so that it looked to itself for the site.`